# What permission level does a user need to execute Recycle() method?

Tags: 2010, development, recycle-bin

In my code, I call the Recycle() method for my SPList object. But I am getting this error for certain users (not for the Site Collection Administrator):

```
<nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr>
```

I am thinking it is a permissions issue. But is it for the list, the Recycle Bin, or the Site? Does anyone know the minimum permission level for a user to execute the Recycle() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users who have Full Control(Site Owners group) or Design ( Designer group )or Edit (site members group) permission level can delete lists.

[image]

The right to delete list is provided via the `Manage Lists` permission level. So any user who has this permission level is able to delete the list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was able to work that out, but you gave a good answer for future Googling. As it turns out, I just used elevated permissions so I wouldn't have to give that level of permission.